# Get SQL tables only not views?

Tags: mysql

`SHOW TABLES`

This lists the view also.

But I don't want the view in the list.

How can I write the Query and get that?

I am using Mysql 5 and MyIsAm is my DB engine.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

If you need to filter it based on schema, then you can add:

```
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_name'
```

Take a look at the information_schema.tables table and you'll see other ways to filter the list.

Comment: I tried this and I got it `SHOW FULL Tables WHERE Table_type="BASE TABLE"`